# Affdex SDK camera detector LNk2019

Tags: c++, camera, lnk2019, unresolved-external, affdex-sdk

I am trying to use the Affdex SDK to determine the emotions of someone through facial recognition. When on their website it says the first thing to do is to create a CameraDetector. They say to do:

```
CameraDetector detector = new CameraDetector();
```

But this will give me this error when building my project in Visual Studios Express 2013:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 
'affdex::CameraDetector *' to 'affdex::CameraDetector'
```

So I made the detector a pointer. Now when I build I get this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) 
public: __thiscall 
affdex::CameraDetector::CameraDetector(int,double,double,unsigned int,enum 
affdex::FaceDetectorMode)" (__imp_??
0CameraDetector@affdex@@QAE@HNNIW4FaceDetectorMode@1@@Z) referenced in 
function _main
```

I am pretty sure that I have the SDK lined properly. I followed the tutorial that is on the Affdex development website.
My main file looks like this:

```
#include <Face.h>
#include <FaceListener.h>
#include <Frame.h>
#include <FrameDetector.h>
#include <ImageListener.h>
#include <PhotoDetector.h>
#include <ProcessStatusListener.h>
#include <typedefs.h>
#include <VideoDetector.h>

using namespace affdex;

int main() {
    CameraDetector *detector = new CameraDetector();
}
```

Is this wrong? Why am I getting a LNK2019 error?

Comment: Literally none of that "duplicated question" helped. I had already looked at that. I linked all the .lib's properly. This question is specifically asking about that error with respect to the Affdex SDK.

Comment: I found out what was causing it. I was using the 64bit version of the sdk. For some reason I was not able to do that. When I am using the 32bit sdk I can compile it.

Comment: The tutorial is using C# not C++ syntax .. hence the syntax error.